# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage — Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs When upload myApp

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, app-store

I tried to upload the app to the App Store, but there was a problem. I received an email telling me not to use `UIWebView` and was rejected.

> App Store Connect   Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "gamemain" 1.0.0 (1). Your delivery was successful, but you may
>   wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more
>   information.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

But I don't use `UIWebView` and I only use `WKWebView`. So I did a full search to see if the library is using it. But nothing was searched. What's the problem?

**Search results for shift + command + F**

[image]

**Web View Usage Classes**

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Toaster
import StoreKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Alamofire

class kWebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,  NASWallDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var kWebView: WKWebView!
```

**podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'gamemain' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

    # Pods for DeleteMe
    pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Toaster'
    pod 'BigInt', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'web3.swift.pod', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.2'
end
```

[image: get]

[image]

I'm sure you'll solve this problem.

Comment: try `pod update` once and then try to upload. maybe framework updated.

Comment: @NiravKotecha  It wasn't the Ford problem that had a problem with me. The naswall.a file in Object-C folder was a problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Apple recently introduced a new App Submission warning **ITMS - 90809** stating that we are formally deprecating `UIWebView`. If your application code or any framework still contains the reference for `UIWebView` for sure you will be get warned.

`WKWebView` is the replacement for `UIWebView` and I believe soon Apple will start rejecting the apps who still use `UIWebView`. So be ready for this.

By executing the below terminal command you can easily get to know which library is still using `UIWebView` reference (don't miss the . (dot)).

```
$ grep -r "UIWebView" .
```

*Output for framework match*

```
./<ANY>.framework/Headers/ANY.h:#define ANYUseUIWebView ANY_NAME_PASTE(ANY_PREFIX_NAME, ANYUseUIWebView)
```

*Output for library match*

```
Binary file ./<FRAMEWORK-NAME>.framework/<LIB-FILE>.a matches
```

If you see some matches it means it time to upgrade these libraries.

I hope it helps. Cheers

**EDIT**

Update from Apple

```
The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of 
April 2020 and app updates using UIWebView as of December 2020.
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b

Comment: What's your source on the April 2020 deadline for completely replacing UIWebview?

Comment: @PatrickCavanagh I came to know when I asked this question to one of the apple engineer and now I feel it doesn't make sense to write it as deadline so I edited the answer. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: @PatrickCavanagh it's official now https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b

Answer (score 0):

In mac, this command worked for me

```
sudo grep -wil -r “uiwebview” .
```

You can go to your project folder and run the above mentioned command.
It'll list down all the files which are using UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue by following these steps

- Open ios project on **Xcode** and searching  **UIWebView**.
- It's shown on the result which dependency is using **UIWebView**.
- Then try to update your dependency.
- Make sure new dependency is not using **UIWebView** following 1st step .

For my case this library using UIWebView  **flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1** 
and replaced **flutter_facebook_auth: ^0.2.3**

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did `grep -r "uiwebview" .` command and it shows many files as shown in attached image .

For the pods in the end I know I should update them but what about the files in my project however I am sure I don't have uiwebview in my project at all[image].